# A reader for big HTML files and/or zipped HTML bundles?

Tags: browser, ebook-reader, ebooks

I'd like to read a moderately big HTML file - about 3M. Another option is to have it split in several interlinked HTMLs.

[Cool reader](http://code.google.com/p/coolreader/) is the closest. Though it:

- either crashes/gets out of memory, I don't know, on certain pages of 3M HTML file (3M not that much, actually, for a 50M free memory).
- or doesn't support links to files lying in the same directory/zip file (in a form: a href="file.html#anchor")

Are there any other options around?

Comment: Have you tried converting this HTML file to a compatible eBook reader friendly format like ePub or plain text? You can use Calibre on your PC to convert the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the default Android browser.  Open the browser, in the address bar enter: `file://sdcard/file.html` (replace the part after `sdcard/` with whatever path leads to your file).  You can then bookmark the file and open it later in the browser without having to re-type the address.  However, trying to make a "bookmark shortcut" or using the HTC bookmark widget will not work for local files.

Answer (score 1):

After testing several browsers (Dolphin, Firefox, Opera) and Readers (Moon+) mentioned in similar questions here, only

[**Offline Browser**](https://market.android.com/details?id=it.nikodroid.offline)

seems to do the Job of reading interlinked offline .html/.htm files correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Moon+ Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader) has the ability to view HTML files - not the code, mind you, just the rendered part. It's an eBook reader and is available in both free and paid versions.

Comment: It wasn't even able to open my file - it crashed 8(
Though, I can always file a bug report...

Comment: Nice reader! Like it, but for the interlinked offline htm books it doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try iReader: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.chaozh.iReader&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jaGFvemguaVJlYWRlciJd